How to reliably locate frames in playwright when the name keeps changing?
I am working on automating salesforce and I am having trouble with the following statement. I keep getting error:
expect(page1.locator("iframe[name=\"vfFrameId_1731538889056\"]").content_frame().get_by_role("row", name="User Detail Edit Sharing").locator("input[name=\"login\"]")).to_be_visible()

The name "vfFrameId_1731538889056" will keep changing everytime and I've tried a few things to no avail. Please share your ideas(if any).
Some of the things I have tried with no success:
Used css selector:
iframe_locator = page1.frame_locator("#setupComponent > div.setupcontent > div > div > force-aloha-page > div > iframe")
content_frame = iframe_locator.frame_locator("iframe").locator("input[name='login']")
expect(content_frame).to_be_visible()

`

SalesForce has extensive facilities for integrating custom code, or manipulating data through an API. Why aren't you using those capabilities rather than trying to manipulate a web page remotely?

I will explore other options, but the question still remains how do I solve this problem using playwright where the iframe name can keep changing?

Can you share the site and your actual goal? You can use partial selectors, but there might be an even easier way to achieve whatever your real goal is.

frame_name = page1.locator("css=#setupComponent > div.setupcontent > div > div > force-aloha-page > div > iframe").get_attribute("name") logger.debug(f"Frame Name:  {frame_name}")     page1.locator(f"iframe[name=\"{frame_name}\"]").content_frame().get_by_role("row", name="User Detail Edit Sharing").locator("input[name=\"login\"]").click()
Changed the code to get the frame name, but despite that, I keep getting an error: TypeError: 'FrameLocator' object is not callable
